# How can i count number of directories in current folder?

Tags: bash, ant

I want to count the number of directories in each folder it traverses. If a number of folders are equal to one, continue traversing, else select the current folder path.

I just want the path of the folder before it branches out.

I am editing this and including a pseudo-code of what I want.

```
IF     There are no .class files in the current directory
AND    Multiple Folders in the current directory
THEN   Use this folder path
```

More Edit:

How would I code this in Ant or Bash? I am opening this question to Bash too. I can execute this code through Ant.

Edit (12 May)

Right now I am using

```
<first>
    <fileset dir="${classes.dir}" includes="/*">
        <include name="**/*.class" />
    </fileset>
</first>
```

which gets me the first .class it searches in alphabetical order. Which I then get the path of by

```
<property name="classloc" value="${classes.dir}" relative="true" basedir="." />
```

This works fine when the folder structure of a project is like this:

[image: Linear Folder Structure]

But when folder structure is branched out and no .class is outside in the root folder then my code only get the path to one of the folders and all other folders are ignored. I need a path to the folder just before the .class files and their folders.

[image: Branched out folders]

Comment: I don't understand this question - maybe if you could show what you've tried so far, or show some examples it might help?

Comment: @martinclayton i want path of the folder before it branches out in different folders. I tired the code below but it give me the first occurrence of the file class. : <first>
        <fileset dir="${classes.dir}" includes="/*">
            <include name="**/*.class" />
        </fileset>
    </first>

Comment: @martinclayton this code get whatever it gets first alphabetically. so in starting folder, if there is a file named A.class it will get it. which is good if the folders were structured that way. the problem occurs when the folder structure of the project is organized in multilevel folders. like starting folder> A folder, B folder, C folder. A folder has A.class and B folder has B.class. so the path the first will get is starting folder> A folder. it leaves all the other files in the B folder and C folder and goes farther into A folder.

Comment: @martinclayton The tool I am using can't scan all the folders if I gave it the starting folder it needs to have the path when the file is closest to .class files. so I need to give target>classes>org>apache>project. I can't just give it the target folder as a path as it won't scan anything in dept. I would have to give it a path to the project folder. so if the project contains all the .class files then perfect. but problems occur when the project has no .class file and just more folders that contain more .class files. The code above will lead me to one of the many folders and leave others.